# Intune user deployment failed

Tags: intune, creative-cloud

when I am adding user in security group in Intune (which I made to test deployment) to deploy creative cloud it fails and when I add device in security group it works. what can be the problem.

I read error and it says: - The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)

which means, Intune could not find the creative cloud file in system! so, there can be something wrong with my detection rule, my detection rule is, it will check if creative Cloud.exe files exist in the system or not and path for that file is **C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Creative Cloud\ACC**.

Comment: Issue might be related to the detection rule that you have set up. It's possible that the detection rule is not able to find the creative cloud file on the user's device specified path. confirm that the file path is correct and that the file is present on the user's device.

You can also try testing the detection rule by running it manually on a user's device to see if it correctly detects the file.

Also, check if the user has the necessary permissions to access the file and if there are any restrictions in place. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/app-detection-rule-windows